# Why calling SetConsoleCtrlHandler() triggers a warning?

Tags: c, windows, mingw, compiler-warnings

```c
#include <windows.h>

BOOL MyCtrlHandler(DWORD ctrlType) {
    return TRUE;
}

int main(void) {
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(MyCtrlHandler, TRUE);
    return 0;
}
```

The function signature matches the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine):

> The PHANDLER_ROUTINE type defines a pointer to this callback function. HandlerRoutine is a placeholder for the application-defined function name.

If I cross-compile it with MinGW in 64 bits, it works:

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc ctrl.c
$
```

But in 32 bits, I get a warning:

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc ctrl.c
ctrl.c: In function ‘main’:
ctrl.c:8:27: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘SetConsoleCtrlHandler’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    8 |     SetConsoleCtrlHandler(MyCtrlHandler, TRUE);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                           |
      |                           BOOL (*)(DWORD) {aka int (*)(long unsigned int)}
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/windows.h:74,
                 from ctrl.c:1:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/wincon.h:249:68: note: expected ‘PHANDLER_ROUTINE’ but argument is of type ‘BOOL (*)(DWORD)’ {aka ‘int (*)(long unsigned int)’}
  249 |   WINBASEAPI WINBOOL WINAPI SetConsoleCtrlHandler(PHANDLER_ROUTINE HandlerRoutine,WINBOOL Add);
      |
$
```

I don't understand why, because `MyCtrlHandler` should have the same type as `PHANDLER_ROUTINE`.

Comment: The link you give says `BOOL WINAPI HandlerRoutine(_In_ DWORD dwCtrlType);` Is it necessary to use the *exact* same definition? Which would be `BOOL WINAPI MyCtrlHandler(_In_ DWORD ctrlType);`

Comment: Yup, I tried it as `BOOL WINAPI MyCtrlHandler(DWORD ctrlType)` and it compiles just fine, without it, I got `Error C2440 'function': cannot convert from 'BOOL (__cdecl *)(DWORD)' to 'PHANDLER_ROUTINE'...`
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the difference between __cdecl and __stdcall.  You must have lucked out with the default calling convention on your one successful attempt to compile.  You need:

```
BOOL WINAPI MyCtrlHandler(DWORD ctrlType) {
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: In x64 cdecl and stdcall, are the same. In x86, on the other hand, cdecl has the caller clean (pop) the stack, while stdcall has the callee clean the stack.

Comment: @ErykSun,  Ah yes, I have been aware of that difference in the past, and completely forgot about it.  Thanks.